# Oracle; two dates, difference in minutes

Tags: oracle, date, difference

I want to obtain the diffenece in minutes as integer between the sysdate and utcdate. this does not work:

```
select ROUND((sysdate-SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP))*1440,0) from dual
```

It gives the error message:
 ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
 Script line 21, statement line 1, column 52

What to do? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  YOu have to convert the systimestamp data type to a date type before you can do math on the two dates.  Maybe there is a more elegant solution, but this seem to work.

```
SELECT ROUND (  (  SYSDATE
                 - TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (SYS_EXTRACT_UTC (SYSTIMESTAMP),
                                     'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS'
                                    ),
                            'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS'
                           )
                )
              * 1440,
              0
             )
  FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Can be simplified a little. `(sysdate - cast(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC (SYSTIMESTAMP) as date)) * 1440`. There is really no need to do *back and forth*  conversion in this situation.

Comment: THanks that is cleaner.